# Failed to save value select option

Tags: laravel, view, html-select

what's wrong in my project.
I want to save with select option, but the filed doesn't save data select option. it just save input text. 
the project is taken different table, and the form just get the `project_name` and `project_id`. `project_id`  will save in in table `spent_times`. 
and the select option will save `task_category` in table `spent_times`

this my model

```
protected $table = 'spent_times';
protected $fillable = [
    'task_category',
    'story/meeting_name',
    'assign',
    'estimated_time', 
    'user_story',
    'spent_time',
    'percentage',
    'lateness',
    'index',
    'project_id'
];

public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function project() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

my create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 <div class="box-body">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Project *</label>
       <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
          <option>Select One</option>
            @foreach($projects as $id => $project)
              <option value="{{$id}}">{{$project}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Story # Meeting Name *</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_story">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Category *</label>
       <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
         <option>Select One</option>
           @foreach($task_categories as $category)
             <option value="{{$category}}">{{$category}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Estimated *</label>                  
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estimated_time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-footer">
    <a href="{{route('index')}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" style="border-radius : 0px;">SAVE</button>
     </a>
   </div>
 </form>
```

my controller

```
public function create()
{          
    $spentimes = new SpentTime;  
    $project = new Project;      
    $projects = Project::select('project_name', 'id')->get();      
    return view('Ongoings.index', compact ('projects', 'task_categories', 'spentimes', 'project'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $spentime = SpentTime::create([
        'project_name' => request('project_name'),
        'user_stroy' => request ('user_story'),
        'task_category' => request('task_category'),
        'estimated_time' => request('estimated_time')
    ]);
    $spentime->save();
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

error like this
[error in web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib8ld.png)

please help me

Comment: your `SpentTime::create()` functions parameters does not match `spent_times` tables columns in the database. first check the `$request` using `dd($request->all());`

Comment: this my model

protected $table = 'spent_times';
    protected $fillable = [
        'task_category',
        'story/meeting_name',
        'assign',
        'estimated_time',
        'user_story',
        'spent_time',
        'percentage',
        'lateness',
        'index',
        'project_id'
    ];

     public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

Comment: can i create a field in two different tables.?

Comment: what is most important is your table structure and `$request` value list. because it seems like in `$request` doesn't has `task_caegory`

Comment: when i use `dd($request->all());` the field task_category doesn't post in db

Comment: of course, it stops the code here, and you can observe whats in the $request. just to make sure yur request contains task_category. so observe it

Comment: can you show the true answer.?

Comment: ok, I'll try to explain what's going on here. you are trying to insert data into database which are 'sent by a request'. and error occurs 'null value for a field'. that means the value has not sent from the request. first you need to check that. that's why i said use `dd($request->all()` and check it first. unless you make sure there is a 'task_category' value in the request, we can't proceed any further. we cant give you a SOLUTION until we figure out the ISSUE. even 'Md Sabbir Ahmed' has pointed out the same thing in the other answer.

Comment: If you don't have any idea how to use `dd()` and figure out errors. contact me and i will help you personally outside the 'stack overflow'

Comment: when I try `dd($request->all()` show this 
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "B0G06nz5OxQrdTUBEqOixzLc85bnjEfilNNonZbP"
  "user_story" => "meeting with client"
  "estimated_time" => "4.00"
]

Comment: the project ang tas_category doesn't send data

Comment: see that's the problem. edit your question and paste the full code of the particular  `<form>`

Comment: so, can you correct my fault.?

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting those fields from request in [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NGTq.png).

- `project_id`
- `meeting_name`
- `task_category`
- `estimated_time`

But You are just sending `estimated_time`,
other 3 fields are not present in you [create.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVLlC.png)

**In create.blade.php, category select input don't have any name.** 
that's why `task_category` is getting null from `request('task_category')`. But `task_category` field is not nullable in your database table.

Send form input properly as you are expecting in your controller. You can use `dd($request->all())` to check.

Comment: i just send certain field in my db

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your `task_category` select box.

so this select box doesn't have a **name attribute**. that's the error.

Possible solution.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Category *</label>
    <select name="task_category" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
         <option>Select One</option>
         @foreach($task_categories as $category)
             <option value="{{$category}}">{{$category}}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: still error, the tas_category doesn't send the data

Comment: can you show me the output of the `dd($request->all())` as  a screenshot?

Comment: this the screenshot `dd($request->all())`
![dd($request)](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/--gqIWQZb-cE/W7QeLISLUII/AAAAAAAAA38/k00_8-tpG9AbA111okYvfFvaRrxMewkIgCLcBGAs/s1600/dd.JPG)